# Reference to type bitmap claims it is defined in system.drawing but it could not be found

Tags: c#, .net-standard-2.0

I have a project using .Net Standard 2.0. And I am getting an error "Reference to type Bitmap claims it is defined in System.Drawing but it could not be found". Does .Net Standard 2.0 not support System.Drawing? Is there any alternative that I can use instead?

Comment: Did you add the System.Drawing.Common NuGet package?

Comment: "Does .Net Standard 2.0 not support System.Drawing?" - **no, it does not**, because `System.Drawing` is just a thin wrapper over GDI which is Win32-specific, whereas .NET Standard is cross-platform.

Comment: @Dai Can you please tell me what else to use to support Bitmap.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Yes System.Drawing.Common version 7.0

Comment: What is your aim? Why are you targeting .NET Standard 2.0 if you want to write Windows-only code? (Even `System.Drawing.Common` [is Windows-only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only))

Comment: @Dai I am comparing PDF's and it has images(Bitmap). So while doing this it throws this error.

Comment: ...in then you should not be targeting .NET Standard 2.0 then. Why are you targeting it?

Comment: I am converting an existing .NetFramework project to .NetStandard so that I can refer it in a .NetCore application

Comment: Don't do that. It won't work. Besides, you can't use .NET Standard as a target for application projects. Just migrate directly to .NET Core 3.1 or later.